# many array element and i need to search a file and print array whcih are not present in the file and there should be no duplicate records in my output

Tags: arrays, linux, shell

Please help me on the below code :

I have an array with 155 elements and i have a file which has some elements of array inside it , i need all values of the array elements which are found in the file and also i need the array element to be printed as zero if the array element is not found in the file .

Thanks in advance, this is what i have tried.

```
args=("C9" "DP10" "DP11" "DP20" "DP21" "DP30" "DP31" "DP50" "FR31" "G128" "G402" "G602" "GA" "GI" "GT08" "GT14" "GT17" "GT25" "GT37" "GT67" "H6" "H7" "IL" "IM" "J6" "JD05" "JD09" "JD14" "JD25" "JD37" "K1" "K2" "L100" "L106" "L116" "L150" "L202" "L7" "L8" "L9" "LD11" "LD21" "LE09" "LE26" "LP11" "LP21" "LP31" "LP55" "LQ11" "LQ21" "LQ31" "LS07" "LT09" "LT10" "LT12" "LT15" "LT20" "LT22" "LT24" "LT25" "LT30" "LT38" "LT42" "LT43" "LT44" "LT48" "LT50" "LT59" "LT60" "LT65" "M395" "OV04" "OV07" "OV14" "OV18" "OV23" "OV27" "OV35" "OV39" "OV40" "OV79" "Q15" "Q150" "Q19" "QD11" "QD21" "QD31" "QD65" "QE11" "QE21" "QE31" "QF50" "QM25" "QP10" "QP15" "QP20" "QP30" "QP31" "QP50" "QT25" "QT50" "R39" "R40" "r57" "R9" "rc23" "RC27" "RC39" "rc7" "rc79" "S1" "S101" "S117" "S118" "S13p" "S18" "S202" "S317" "S318" "S319" "S40" "S408" "S67" "S76" "S82" "S99" "SD11" "SD12" "SD14" "SD17" "SD29" "SD3" "SD5" "SD98" "SF20" "SF74" "SR07" "SV19" "SV6p" "T402" "T602" "TG00" "TG17" "TG43" "TG8" "TG92" "WD09" "WD14" "WD17" "WD24" "WD29" "WD37" "WD43" "WWE1" "XR91")
```

MY CODE :

for loop i have used to traverse the elements search inside a file .

```
    for i in ${args[@]}; do
        grep $i file.txt
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo $i"","""0"
        fi
    done >> output.txt
```

TOTAL FILE:

```
C9,5015319
DP10,36870732
DP11,188
DP20,18728254
DP21,341182
DP30,8415555
DP31,2390000
DP50,12371853
FR31,24541
G128,49780
G402,2000
G602,2000
GA,879888
GT08,1580384
GT17,1968192
GT25,4104
GT37,21550
GT67,24770
H6,660652
IL,137651
JD05,1518400
JD14,325800
JD25,828600
JD37,357100
K1,261549
K2,4715330
L100,284
L116,80000
L7,200847
L8,3158
L9,5054495
LE09,75776
LE26,343410
LP11,1030
LP21,492
LP31,113
LP55,3
LQ11,6776000
LQ21,3543600
LQ31,4525600
LT09,682800
LT12,5715
LT15,568873
LT22,236077
LT24,702800
LT25,4600
LT38,28990
LT65,300125
M395,29600
OV14,462
OV18,86300
OV40,217899
Q150,678
QD11,1000022
QD31,50
QF50,58575
QM25,57900
QP10,1792153
QP15,953400
QP20,770000
QP30,179450
QP31,163223
QP50,8
QT50,66340
R39,62440
R40,18807
r57,3456
rc23,3370
RC27,2809
RC39,2570
rc7,7137
rc79,1296
S1,25007
S117,1000000
S13p,52313
S18,75000
S317,289148
S318,3046
S319,30000
S40,300
S408,4967
S76,28
S82,103238
S99,480
SD11,6719
SD12,23123
SD14,22595
SD17,100000
SD29,252392
SD3,20000
SD5,14090
SD98,653
SF20,1000
SF74,7330
SV19,26461
SV6p,154994
T402,2000
T602,2000
TG17,2031
TG8,2964
TG92,1759
WD17,131194
WD24,94589
WD29,202198
WD37,101794
WD43,112942
WWE1,9600
XR91,70000
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT :

The output should contain the values which are present in the file for each array element.

If not present the output should contain the array element as zero. For eg:

```
c9 is not present in the file 

output of c9 should be 

c9,0
```

Comment: Kindly help me asap . !!

Comment: What exactly is your question? Pure "write code for me" questions don#t work well on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Pekka웃: The OP is providing code (near the end of the posting). I agree with you that it is not clear where s/he wants help.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not bad. I just would use

```
^$i,
```

as a grep-pattern. With your current file data, it's not necessary, but maybe one day your file will contain things like

```
X,2354
XA,1234
```

and suddenly your algorithm will fail, if `args` contain the element `X`.

Also, the `echo` statement is unnecessarily complex. I would write it simply as

```
echo $x,0
```

You can also simplify the  `if`, by combining it with the `grep`

```
if ! grep ^$i, file.txt
```

but this is mere cosmetics and a matter of taste.

Comment: hello, 

Can you give me complete script ?

Comment: I don't get the meaning of your question. You posting already contains a complete script. Now you are free to incorporate my suggestions. What else are you looking for?

Comment: @Govins: I just see that you have edited your posting. You have removed your script (why did you do this?) and added information about the expected output. Still, I don't understand your exact question. Please clarify, what exactly you want to know.

Comment: is it to be changed as :

#!/bin/bash
args=("C9" "DP10" "DP11" "DP20" "DP21" "DP30" "DP31" "DP50" "FR31" "G128" "G402" "G602" "GA" "GI" "GT08" "GT14" "GT17" ""WD24" "WD29" "WD37" "WD43" "WWE1" "XR91")
for i in ${args[@]}; do
   grep $i file.txt
#    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
 if ! grep ^$i, file.txt
        echo $i,0
    fi
done >> file.txt_temp

Comment: If you post code in this way in a comment, it is practically not legible. Please add this information (properly formatted) to your original posting.